# Delete selected rows in uitable - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I built in GUI (using  GUIDE) a uitable (4x5) that last row is logical so I can select lines to delete.

```
d = {'L1',1,10,true;'L2',2,20,true;'L3',3,30,false;'L4',4,40,true;'L4',5,50,false};
set(handles.outputTable,'Data',d)
```

I created a button to delete the selectd rows but I does not work:

```
function deleteButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to deleteButton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
dataTable = (get(handles.outputTable,'data'));

[m n] = size(dataTable);

disp(dataTable);

for i = 1:m
    if num2str(cell2mat(dataTable(i,4))) =='1'    
      dataTable(i,:)=[];
    end
end

disp('Modifed table')
disp(dataTable);
```

How can I fix it so I get set the table again in the GUI?

Comment: (1) You first get the `data` from the `uitable` in your variable `dataTable` =>ok. Then (2) you modify the `dataTable` according to your needs => ok. Now you just need to complete the process: (3) push your `dataTable` back into the `uitable`, something like `set(handles.outputTable,'data',dataTable)`.

Comment: I get an error with the loop, the rows are not deleted. Any idea why?

Comment: you don't need `num2str` and `cell2mat` to just check for a boolean value in a cell array. You could try just checking for `if dataTable{i,4} ; dataTable(i,:)=[]; end`. Note the use of the **curly braces:** `{...}` instead of the parenthesis, when you want to retrieve the _content_ of a given `cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
for i = 1:m
    if num2str(cell2mat(dataTable(i,4))) =='1'    
      dataTable(i,:)=[];
    end
end
```

First of all, `if num2str(cell2mat(dataTable(i,4))) =='1'` is a convoluted equivalent of `if dataTable{i,4}==1`. You should learn to use curly braces `{}` to access the content of a cell array.

Then, it will work only if the counter is decreased.
See what happens:

```
Test if row n should be deleted
Delete line n; the content of row (n+1) have now moved to row n
Increment counter i from value n to n+1
The row now at position n has never been tested for deletion !
```

What was at row (n+1) is never tested, since the delete operation moves it backwards first, then the counter is incremented without testing again. The solution is to decrement the counter.

```
for i = m:-1:1
    if dataTable{i,4}   
      dataTable(i,:)=[];
    end
end
```

The rows moved by the deletion operation have already been tested, so in the end it is certain that all lines will have been tested.

Now, the same can be obtained in a vectorized form with a single line:

```
dataTable = dataTable(cell2mat(dataTable(:,4))==0,:);
```

The whole function boils down to:

```
function deleteButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    dataTable = get(handles.outputTable,'data');
    % Do some checks to make sure that the values input by are correct %
    assert(all(cellfun(@isscalar,dataTable(:,4))), 'Last colum should contain scalars!');
    set(handles.outputTable,'data' , dataTable(cell2mat(dataTable(:,4))==0,:));
end
```